# Excel Conditional formatting for Columns

Tags: excel

In Excel how to change the 3rd column color if any changes happen to Col1 and col2 using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will be only possible with VBA (Event Change). If you want this conditional formatting to be applied to Sheet1, then go to VBA > double-click on Sheet1 > paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("C:C").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
End Sub
```

Now if you go back to Sheet1 and do any change to either column A or B, your column C should change its fill colour to blue.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding..
But I Want to colorize the consecutive cell only.

Comment: Hi, do you mean you would like to colorize only those cells (column C) that are in the same row as those in columns A:B that have changed? For example, if cell A12 changes, you would like to change the color of C12; if cell B56 changes, you would like to change the color of C56, etc?